# Emacs hangs for seconds when writing file, to do with kjournald and VirtualBox

Tags: emacs, delay, virtual-machine

I run

```
GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, Xaw3d scroll bars)
of 2010-12-12 on brahms, modified by Debian
```

on

```
Linux version 2.6.32-5-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-34squeeze1) (dannf@debian.org) 
(gcc version 4.3.5 (Debian 4.3.5-4) ) #1 SMP Wed May 18 23:13:22 UTC 2011
```

When saving files, emacs sometimes takes 3 seconds to write a small file to disc.
I ran iotop and found that kjournald seems to be responsible for the delay:

```
423 be/4 root        0.00 B/s   19.00 K/s  0.00 % 99.85 % [kjournald]
```

This process sits there on 99 percent while emacs hangs, sometimes for a few seconds.

It looks like the writing delay issue has to do with the virtual machine (Windows 7 in VirtualBox) that shares the file system I am writing to. After closing the virtual machine the delays do not occur. 
kjournald still makes an appearance in iotop, but stays at 0% and is immediately done.

I am no expert in this, so any suggestions how to tackle the write delay problem are much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "shares the filesystem"?